Sharing authentication cookie between Web and Api projects in Net Core 8
I'm trying to configure shared authentication between a Razor Pages project and a Web Api project in the same solution.
I've followed the instructions in this article and I've been able to create a sample solution with the two projects and an InMemory database that works perfectly on my laptop.
When I try to run the same sample on my development machine (still using localhost but with a different port number for the two projects) it doesn't work. I've tried the same steps to make another test solution directly on the development machine, and I still can't get it to work. If I use the swagger interface to register a user, and then log in with that user, that same cookie doesn't get picked up by the Razor Pages app (but in my original test solution on the laptop it does, all I have to do is press refresh after logging in with Swagger and it shows me logged in with the correct user name in both apps). I'm assuming there is a configuration issue with the development machine, but I can't work it out.
Razor Pages project Program.cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseInMemoryDatabase("TestDb"));

builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

builder.Services.AddRazorPages();

builder.Services.AddDataProtection()
    .PersistKeysToFileSystem(new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Visual Studio 2022\TestApiSecurity.Web"))
    .SetApplicationName("TestApp");

builder.Services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
{
    options.Cookie.Name = ".TestApp.SharedCookie";
    options.Cookie.Path = "/";
});

var app = builder.Build();

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseMigrationsEndPoint();
}
else
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapRazorPages();

app.Run();


Web Api project Program.cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseInMemoryDatabase("TestDb"));

builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

builder.Services.AddAuthorization();

builder.Services.AddIdentityApiEndpoints<IdentityUser>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

builder.Services.AddDataProtection()
    .PersistKeysToFileSystem(new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Visual Studio 2022\TestApiSecurity.Web"))
    .SetApplicationName("TestApp");

builder.Services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
{
    options.Cookie.Name = ".TestApp.SharedCookie";
    options.Cookie.Path = "/";
});


var app = builder.Build();

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.MapIdentityApi<IdentityUser>();

app.Run();


These codes are correct. My test also works well. I think it may be the PersistKey folder access problem, you could try some other folder to see if the issue replicates.

So just checking the write permissions of the asp.net account? Is there a way to do that in the asp.net config? Similar to impersonate in the old web.config?

You could use "process monitor" to catch "access denied" event.  https://helpdeskgeek.com/windows-10/how-to-use-process-monitor-and-process-explorer/
